# How to display grid footer values using Kendo UI mvc extensions

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

The kendo docs are pretty horrid and most of them are geared towards the pure javascript implementation.

I'm trying to display grid footer values and I pieced some samples together to come up with the following but my footer values show up blank.

I see the values coming back in the request as part of the JSON returned but the values seem to be null when accessing them in the template.

I've tried `(Sum)` and `(Sum.Value)` although `Sum.Value` returns an error saying the sum property is null.

```
@{ var g = Html.Kendo().Grid<OrderViewModel>()
  .Name("Orders")
  .Columns(c =>
  {
      c.Bound(p => p.OrderID).Title("ID").Width(80);
      c.Bound(p => p.OrderDate).Width(105).Format("{0:d}").Title("Date");
      c.Bound(p => p.Name).Title("Name").FooterTemplate(i => i.Count);
      c.Bound(p => p.Company).Title("Company");
      c.Bound(p => p.Email);
      c.Bound(p => p.Phone).Title("Phone");
      c.Bound(p => p.Total).Width(100).Format("{0:c}").FooterTemplate(@<text>@item.Sum</text>);
      c.Bound(p => p.Approved).Width(100);
      c.Command(command => { command.Edit().Text("&#x200b;").UpdateText("&#x200b;").CancelText("&#x200b;"); }).Width(154);
  })
    .DataSource(d => d
        .Ajax()
        .Aggregates(aggregates => {
            aggregates.Add(a => a.Total).Sum();
            aggregates.Add(a => a.Name).Count();
        })
        .Read(a => a.Action("GetOrders", "Orders"))
        .Update(a => a.Action("UpdateOrder", "Orders"))
        .PageSize(10)
        .Sort(sort => sort.Add("OrderDate").Descending())
        .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.ID))
        )
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Filterable()
    .Editable(e => e.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
    .Resizable(r => r.Columns(true));
    @g
}
```

Any ideas what I am missing?

The aggregates section is from their samples, but the same sample doesn't bother to show the template itself.

I also tried count but no luck. See my bound columns `(Name)` and `(Total)`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that if you are using Ajax Binding rather than Server Binding in your datasource then you have to use Client Templates.

eg.

Replace

```
c.Bound(p => p.Total).Width(100).Format("{0:c}").FooterTemplate(@<text>@item.Sum</text>);
```

with

```
c.Bound(p => p.Total).Width(100).Format("{0:c}").ClientFooterTemplate("#=sum#")
```

Hope that helps...
I'm finding the same problems with Docs.